# Check if string has ONLY certain word javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if a string in an array has only a certain word.

```
var nonessential = function(){
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var stringnumber = arr[i];
if (stringnumber.indexOf("the")>-1 || stringnumber.indexOf("this")>-1 || stringnumber.indexOf("than")>-1 || stringnumber.indexOf("a")>-1){
}else{
    essential = arr.slice(i,1)
    console.log(essential)
}
}
```

So, for example, if the array was `["hey","man","a","this"]`, I want the new array (essential) to be `["hey","man"]`. The problem is, because the `indexOf` checks for a, so it eliminates "man". I only want to eliminate the array value if the string is ONLY `"a"`, not it if includes it. Any solutions?

Comment: Why are you using `indexOf` when you want simple string equality? Use `==`.

Comment: Listen to meagar. This is not C and indexOf is not strcmp. You don't need to use functions to compare string equality in a modern language.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). You can use it to remove items from an array based on a predicate function.

```
function nonessential(words) {
  var targetWords = ['the', 'targetRegexthis', 'than', 'a'];
  return words.filter(function(word) {
    return targetWords.indexOf(word) < 0;
  });
}
```

Maybe think about using Regular expressions for more fine grained control when specifying non-essential words.